# How to generate pdf with multiple submit in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I was asked a question in an interview.

> Generate a PDF from multiple submissions. In the image you can see there is one form that contains name, email, phno, and country which will open one by one on click of "next" button and at last there is a "SUBMIT" button (slider I can use for next), which will generate the PDF containing all submitted data for that particular user.
>
> [image]
>
> Don't generate a PDF every time submit is clicked. Instead the user will fill out the form many times and than generate the PDF with all of the entries together in one PDF file.

e.g. I fill this similar form for 5 times, and at the end I will generate PDF all combined data.

Condition is that you can not save in Database or save in session.

Comment: What is your question? You say you were asked this question, but you haven't asked questions about that question, or indicated how you answered it.

Answer (score 0):

You can save in cookie or localstorage tmp data and on finally submit send data to generate pdf